# Android - ListView with AsyncTask implementation using JSOUP

Tags: java, android, html, android-asynctask, jsoup

I need some advice, because this thing took me enough time to be angry on myself for lack of knowledge... I try to make a ListView filled by JSOUP-extracted data. And the JSOUP part is in AsyncTask. Here is my code:

```
public class ListaActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private List<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView mListView;
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    public Elements job;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);  

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new NewThread().execute();
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, mList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.somewebsite.com")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

                title = doc.select("h3.something-to-extract a[href]");

                for (Element titles : title) {
                    mList.add(titles.text()+"\n");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

IMO it is something with JSOUP part, because when I erase all content od `doInBackground` and put inside just

```
mList.add("Something 1");
mList.add("Something 2");
```

then it works. Please help me somehow.

EDIT: I want to parse data from this html fragment:

```
<h2 class="title">
      <a href="/jstpl/london/11697582"  
               title="You just have to wait" class="titles">
                    Nothing else to say
       </a>
```

I wanted to store "`Nothing else to say`" to `mList`, such as another titles existing in my html code. The parsing part alone works good too.

Comment: Can you provide an HTML sample of the title you are trying to extract?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on `mAdapter`. I have posted as ans below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on adapter

Reflect changes in list provided to adapter. To do that -

override `onPostExecute` in your `NewThread` and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

**Note :** `onPostExecute` runs on the main UI thread and not your `NewThread`, where as `doInBackground` runs inside your `NewThread`. And `onPostExecute` is called when the background thread is done processing. Now since we have updated the list with new items. We will notify the adapter running on main thread. Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured out on my own that my adapter doesn't know about list changes, but thanks for telling me how to notify it :) Thanks for everything!